# Identifying a class object with its member integer Id in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl

Look at the three classes and its data members, given below.

**node class**

```
 class node
 {
     int node_id;
     double x,y,z;

 }
```

**element class**

```
 class element
 {
      int element_id;
      node node1,node2,node3;
 }
```

**mesh class**

```
 class mesh
 {
      /* I know that instead of pointer object we've to use smart pointer
         in the vector  but don't know how to use it.Any help is 
         appreciated. */

      std::vector<node*> nodes; // stores node objects.
      std::vector<element*> elements; //store element objects;
 }
```

So I can easily instantiate node objects and can be stored in **nodes** of std::vector data-type. But I need to precisely know which **node** objects are there in the element to instantiate an object of **element**.   node objects are stored in the vector array. Identifying a node object like nodes[i] is error prone in my case (i.e nodes[i] is not the exact i-th node, where i is the node-id) .  So I would like to identify an node object based on its id. Please give me suggestions.

I hope my question make sense. Since I'm a beginner in c++ any edit is also appreciated to make question understandable.

Comment: Please give reason when you downvote

Comment: can you explain " Identifying a node object like nodes[i] is error prone in my case" .. how exactly is it error prone?? ..side note i was not the downvoter so this is not the reson why ur question was downvoted..

Comment: @Hummingbird I can only identify a node object by its node_id. The positioning of node objects in vector array is random. i.e position i in node[i] is not the node_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure weather this is exactly what your problem is but providing a simle `getter` for `id` and then checking it may do as it looks like :

```
 class node
 {
     int node_id;
     double x,y,z;
 public:
     int getId(){ return node_id;}
 }
```

as for smart pointer in `mesh` class you could use

```
 class mesh
 {
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> nodes; // stores node objects.
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<element>> elements; //store element objects;
      void test()
      {
         for(const auto& n : nodes)
         {
            if(n->getId() == /*what you want*/)
            {
                 //emplace/push_back in elements
            }
      }
}
```

for [e.g.](http://ideone.com/TAMdoo)

Comment: Yes, You've correctly understood my problem. In fact, the above method was there in my mind. But for each element initiation, I have to iterate through all of the nodes, right?. If there are thousands of node objects, then this method is quite complex. Is there any simple solution available?

Comment: how about keep on creating the elements as you iterate through `nodes` rather than searching for a `node` and then creating `element`. Is there any specific creteria you wish to create `element`.. may be like in inc. order of `node_id` ??

Comment: There is no specific criteria for creating element with node. An element is collection of nodes and nodes can be shared between elements